Small wall of enclosed porch doesn't seem to be attached to concrete floor anymore, is there something I can reinforce the wall to the floor?
I have an enclosed porch.  the small wall that the storm door is attached to doesn't appear to be anchored to the concrete floor anymore, if it was at all.  Is there anything I can do to re-anchor it to the floor?
The enclosed porch has old school wood paneling in it - this is a 1940s home.  There was some rot in the wood paneling at the base near the door.  The rot is fairly contained in a smallish spot, so I planned on putting some scrape wood in the hole and foaming around it.  While hammering in the scrap wood, the wall moved with it slightly.  I'd say it moved about a half inch.  I went to the other side and got it moved back, but now I'm a little concerned that it moved at all.  It's not wobbly if you grab hold of the window trim and try to move it.  Maybe I shouldn't be concerned

Usually walls are anchored to the floor.  Depending if anything was used, 80 plus years might be enough for rust to do its job.  Anchoring it now will require access to the bottom plate of the wall and then use ram-set nails/concrete anchors.

If you had rot at the bottom of the wall it is very likely that the nails anchoring the wall have rusted.

Angle brackets/L shape steel might also be used to anchor the wall, if do not want to remove enough to nail the bottom plate to the floor. Can screw them into the floor(tapcons) and wall.
